# Converting CFString to CFStringRef and CFErrorRef to CFError in c++

Tags: c++, macos

THE ANSWER ACCEPTED GAVE ME THE CORRECT EXPLANATION OF THE PROBLEM. I ALSO EDITED THE QUESTION PUTTING THE ANSWER POINT BY POINT IN CAPITAL LETTERS TO MAKE IT CLEARER

I have a c++ code in MacOSX, that use a bit of CoreFoundation.

I use the following function `CFPropertyListCreateWithData` in my code that takes a `CFErrorRef *error` as one of its parameters. Well, I create `CFErrorRef myError` and pass it as `&myError`

**First problem:** I think there is a bug in the [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corefoundation/1430002-cfpropertylistcreatewithdata?language=objc), because it gives me some good data as result, but the error is NOT NULL. If I have an error, the data should be NULL, shouldn't it? Or did I misunderstand the documentation?

FIRST SOLUTION: THE ERROR IS UNDEFINED IF THERE IS NO ERROR, SO I HAD TO CHECK THE ERROR ONLY IF THE DATA WERE NULL. MOREOVER I WAS RELEASING USING `CFRelease` A UNDEFINED OBJECT, THE ERROR, THAT CAUSED MY PROGRAM TO CRASH WITH A SEGMENTATION FAULT

**Second problem:** I want to check which is the error.
Well I get into this function `CFErrorCopyFailureReason`, [doc here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corefoundation/1494651-cferrorcopyfailurereason),
 but it takes a CFError and not a CFErrorRef, and gives me a CFString. Then, how can I transform my CFErrorRef to CFError?

SECOND SOLUTION: NOSENSE QUESTION, I WAS READING THE DOCUMENTATION OF SWIFT AND NOT OF OBJECTIVE-C

**Third problem:** the function `CFErrorCopyFailureReason` gives me a `CFString`, but I do not know where the `CFString` is defined! it is not in `CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h` and neither in `CoreFoundation/CFString.h`, and I have a undefined type error when I try to compile.
Then: In which file is `CFString` defined? Can I convert it to `CFStringRef`, and how can I do it?

THIRD SOLUTION: NOSENSE QUESTION, I WAS READING DOCUMENTATION OF SWIFT AND NOT OF OBJECTIVE-C

**Fourth problem:** with the code I have, if I use `CFStringRef` and `CFErrorRef` instead of `CFString` and `CFError`, it compiles, but then I have a `NSInvalidArgumentException`. Shouldn't I have an error at compilation time? I would not like a RunTimeException...

FOURTH SOLUTION: AS THE ANSWER MADE ME UNDERSTAND, I HAD TO CHECK THE ERROR ONLY IF THE DATA WAS NULL. IN THAT CASE I WAS CHECKING A ERROR WITH UNDEFINED DATA THAT GAVE ME THE INVALID ARGUMENT EXCEPTION. OBVIOUSLY, SINCE THE PROBLEM WAS UNDEFINED VALUE IN THE ERROR, THIS IS A RUNTIME EXCEPTION

Well, to conclude, I just want to read and write a `Info.plist` file in my c++ application. I take inspiration from this, [Saving and Restoring Property Lists](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFPropertyLists/Articles/Saving.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001175-CJBEHAAG), sample code and modified it quite a bit. If you have a working sample how to read and modify a `Info.plist` file, please tell me :) but without using *PlistBuddy* or other tools please, only c++ API.

TO CONCLUDE: THE SAMPLE CODE WORKS WELL, I JUST MISUNDERSTOOD THE DOCUMENTATION

Thanks to everybody

Comment: You should show your code. In general, there are plenty of errors that can't be detected at compile time and will only be detected at run time. If you're interested in the properties in a bundle's Info.plist, you should consider the [`CFBundle` API](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corefoundation/cfbundle?language=objc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are misunderstanding the documentation for `CFPropertyListCreateWithData()`: if it succeeds, the return value is non-NULL, and what `error` points to is not defined. Don't worry about `error` unless `CFPropertyListCreateWithData()` returns NULL.

`CFErrorCopyFailureReason()` does take a `CFErrorRef` and return a `CFStringRef`. You might be looking at the Swift documentation for it, change the language to Objective-C on the top of the documentation page.

Which call is throwing the exception, `CFPropertyListCreateWithData()`?

Comment: Hi Brendan, thanks, I think this was the problem. A part that I was seeing the documentation of Swift, as you correctly said, I also misunderstood the documentation. In particular (a part other little problems), I had a segmentation fault and I think because I was trying to use `CFRelease` to release the error in `CFPropertyListCreateWithData` even when the error did not occurr.

Then, in that function, I CFRelease the error ONLY if an error occurred. Can you confirm that this is correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. The header for `CFPropertyListCreateWithData()` states: "If an error occurs while parsing the data, the return value will be NULL. Additionally, if an error occurs and the error parameter is non-NULL, the error parameter will be set to a CFError describing the problem, which the caller must release"